# Hard Start 2007 VW Rabbit 2.5L

Tags: starting, vw

Warm weather (above 50F/10C) after sitting awhile car needs to be cranked 5+ seconds or more. Definitely air in fuel line as about 1/2 mile down road car stutters for a bit. Every time. Cold weather starts fine.
Ongoing for years. Fuel filter/pump/battery have all been changed to no effect.

Comment: What happens, in warm weather, if you let the engine cool completely (say over night)? Do you still get a hard start? How does the engine need to sit before it is hard to start? Have you tried replacing the fuel lines?

Comment: Car starts hard left overnight warm weather. If restarted within 15 minutes of stopping, starts fine. Negetive on fuel lines.

Comment: Have you done a fuel pressure leakdown test? It sounds like it is leaking down overnight when warm. Next time before you start it turn the key on and off a few times, leaving it on for 10 seconds each time to prime the pump. Then see if it starts easily. Might need a fuel pressure regulator.

Comment: @ATC - Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue on my 2007 VW Rabbit

Comment: if everything is not like new what does that mean? I suspect compression as flow gets the engine running but something is taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem I had with an old 1989 VW Rabbit. At that time it turned to be a temperature sensor that had something to do with the injector system. The sensor was located near the cooling system thermostat.

The symptoms were the same. Initial start up OK then 10 minutes later stall. Let cool restart no problem then the process would repeat as before.

Armed with a Volkswagen service manual containing an electrical schematic I figured out  the thermistor characteristics. I then made a trip to Radio Shack to get the 2 thermistors and twisted the leads together and plugged in and tie wrapped that sucker  to the sensor. The jury rigging worked and got me my mechanic...who by the way was seriously impressed.

Your vehicle being a 2007 I imagine such an issue would flag a OBD code. |I hope it points you in the right direction.